# Are the following statements regarding sets true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) $\emptyset - \{1\} = \emptyset$

2) $\{1\} - \{2,3\} = \{1\}$

3) $\{1\} - \emptyset = \{1\}$

I am not really sure about number 1, but if number 2 is correct doesn't that mean number 1 is also correct?

Comment: What do you interpret "$A\setminus B$" as?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: Just checking if my understanding of sets if correct. You can think of the first set of every statement as being A and the second set as being B.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are correct.

$A - B = \{x \in A \mid x \notin B\}$.

Since there are no elements in the empty set, there are no elements in the empty set that are not in set $\{1\}$.  Hence, 
$$\emptyset - \{1\} = \{x \in \emptyset \mid x \notin \{1\}\} = \{x \in \emptyset\} = \emptyset$$

$\{1\} - \{2, 3\} = \{x \in \{1\} \mid x \notin \{2, 3\}\} = \{1\}$ since $1 \notin \{2, 3\}$.

$\{1\} - \emptyset = \{x \in \{1\} \mid x \notin \emptyset\} = \{1\}$ since $1 \notin \emptyset$.